# Local storage usage with Facebook and Safari

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, safari, local-storage

I have a running application on Facebook which uses the local storage to store various items.
When running on chrome or firefox the application works just fine but since Safari's default local storage definition is to block local storage requests that are not from **visited domains**, it automatically blocks my attempts to set/get items from the local storage.
 
The question remains, is it possible to make my local storage items look like they are coming from Facebook (as it is the hosting domain and it wont be blocked) or is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Probably this is not possible, because your application are running on facebook by a `iframe` that facebook creates, with another domain and Safari will not allow it. Try use cookies Instead.

Comment: The thing is safari acts exactly the same with cookies, I did find a php code piece that helps "trick" safari in to accepting my cookies and enabling the use of local storage but the thing is I'm not sure if it's ok to use it since I don't really know much about the subject, as it seems it loads your page on top.location, creates the session and redirects it back to Facebook, is that a legitimate thing to do ?